# PHP delete values from mysql bad

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which works without errors, but can't delete chosen value from mysql.
It looks like: What problem could be?

```
include('opendb.php');
$a = $_GET['new_pav'];
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * from naujiena WHERE new_pav = '$a'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($select)){
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `naujiena` WHERE new_pav='".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."' ");
}
```

Comment: have You checked foreign key relations?

Comment: Please add `or die(mysql_error());` after the `mysql_query`

Comment: You better check whether you get the `GET` parameter properly, and then whether you have a populated resultset as a result of the SELECT statement and finally, whether you ever get into the while loop and if yes, what statements are executed.

Comment: Please don't use the mysql_*-functions anymore. Why: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/765805

Comment: @stUrb It's quite astonishing that people are _still_ using it for new code despite the big shiny red warning box

Comment: -1 since you have mentioned in one of the comments that you have code for mysqli_ library.

Comment: Can you explain everything *in your question* in future, rather than posting an incorrect answer and several comments with code.

Comment: @Bojangles *"If an organism has a choice between two things, the organism will do what it damn well pleases"*

Comment: @Hiroto I'm not sure what you mean by your quote. Are you saying that using deprecated functionality is ok, or that people will often blindly use whatever they are presented with first?

Comment: @Bojangles it's a quote from jeff atwood about how no matter many times you tell someone something, they'll do what they feel like

Comment: Ah, now I see, thanks! I should have known that quote seeing as I read his blog `:P`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [**read this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/765805) (and below):

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

The red warning box is telling you to stop using `mysql_*` in anything new.

As for your query, `DELETE FROM x WHERE y=z` is a valid query, so the error could be from your use of quotes (if `new_pav` is an int, then this could explain it); strings are quoted in MySQL.

Also, do not interpolate/concat strings in an SQL query, or you risk SQL Injection. Look up [pdo](http://php.net/pdo), and start using classes for something that involves a state (the db connection), rather than a variable and countless functions. (I originally used mysqli here):

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM naujiena WHERE new_pav = :pav");

    if (!$query->bindParam(":pav", $_POST["new_pav"])) {
        die("Input incorrect; couldn't bind");
    }

    $query->execute();
    $rows = $query->fetchColumn(0); // fetch a single column. count(*) here.

    if ($rows !== 0) { // It has a result~
        $query = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM naujiena WHERE new_pav = :pav");
        $query->execute(array(":pav" => $_POST["new_pav"]));
    }
    $db = null; // explicitly close connection

} catch (PDOException $e) { // catch any exception PDO throws at you.
    // note that you should catch where appropriate.
    die("Connection Failed: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Note that with SQL Injection, I could type `' OR 1=1 --` and delete your whole table.

As you can see, this is far from a one/two-liner, but **you must *never* trust anything added to SQL that you didn't hardcode in yourself, period.**

Comment: But i need to get an accurate value from database and delete it ;/. For example if i have a new with 3 column such as: 1      New_Name      Istrinti(Delete) so when i click istrinti a new deletes from database.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using `mysql_` libraries your code:

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * from naujiena WHERE new_pav = '$a'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($select)){
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `naujiena` WHERE new_pav='".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."' ");
}
```

In the `SELECT` you are not escaping the value of `$a` but in the delete you are escaping it.

Anyway if you are just doing a delete you do not need the `SELECT` or `while` loop. So you could use the following code:

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `naujiena` WHERE new_pav='".mysql_real_escape_string($a)."' ");
```

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

$db = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(isset($_GET['new_pav'])) {
    $result = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM `naujiena` WHERE new_pav= ? ");
    $result->execute();
    $result->close();

    if($result) {
        echo "succces";
    }
    } 

else {
    die("Nepavyko");
} Check it out

Comment: @user2149578 - I did mention not using mysql_ libraries but fixed your code that uses those deprecated libraries. If you know that these libraries are deprecated why post the code and not code that uses mysqli_ library?